# WSO2 Api Manager using 3rd party authentication service to generate access tokens

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 product suite and have been evaluating (specifically API Manager) for certain scenarios. I have a question regarding using authentication service provided by a legacy application as a way to authenticate the user and generate user access tokens.

To elaborate further, say I have a client application which requires access to a bunch of APIs. So, I go to the store, setup an application and subscribe the APIs that the client needs access to.

Now, I want users of my client application to be able to access these APIs only after proper authentication. For authentication, I have a legacy application which has the user database and exposes a login service. Is there a way to configure API Manager to use such a login service for authentication and then generate the user access tokens to allow the authenticated user access to the subscribed APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to write you own custom authenticator for WSO2 API Manager. It is already explained in the [WSO2 API manger documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Writing+Custom+Handlers)